# iOS GameKit Leaderboard - Get the localplayer's score +/- 50 players around him

Tags: ios, gamekit, leaderboard

I'm programmatically pulling down leaderboard data from game center and I'd like to limit my data query to the local player's score and the 25 scores above and below him.  Is this possible.  Is there a way to get the local player's current position in the leaderboard?

Answer (score 2):

Once you make a call to `[GKLeaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:]` you can use `[[GKLeaderboard localPlayerScore] rank]` to get the rank of the current user.

So the next time you call `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler`, set the range around that value like `leaderboardRequest.range=NSMakeRange(localPlayerRank-25, 50)`

Also make sure you're not querying for a rank less than one!